# What is an instruction when we `add_all_qubit_quantum_error`?

Tags: qiskit, noise, depolarizing-channel

I'm trying to understand how the noise model works in Qiskit Aer noise simulator. From [this information page](https://qiskit.org/documentation/locale/de_DE/stubs/qiskit_aer.noise.NoiseModel.add_all_qubit_quantum_error.html), `add_all_qubit_quantum_error()` has two required arguments: `param`, which specifies the noise strength, and `instructions`, which is ' the instructions error applies to'.

For 1-qubit noise, I noticed the general way to produce a noise model (say the depolarization channel) is

```
error_1 = depolarizing_error(0.1, 1)
depolarizing_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
```

What is the appropriate instruction for 2-qubit circuits? Should I use the following code?

```
error_2 = depolarizing_error(0.1, 2)
depolarizing_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx'])
```

I also noticed if I add any random instructions to the list, like

```
depolarizing_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx','ww','yz1'])
```

It seems like the noise simulation still works. **What is the appropriate way to build a noise model for a 2-qubit circuit? Which kind of instructions should I use?**

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your circuit. If you have only 1-qubit gates, you can construct a noise model from single-qubit errors. But if you want to do something interesting, you need to entangle your qubits with 2-qubit gates. Then you can add a depolarizing error for 2 qubits or a tensor product of two single-qubit errors to the noise model.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you want to apply the same error to any two-qubits gate you use in your circuit or not.

This answer explains it very well
[How to selectively apply noise in Qiskit simulations?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/how-to-selectively-apply-noise-in-qiskit-simulations)
If you want to use different noise for your two-qubit gates you will need to label them and use those labels as instruction