# Apply a single-qubit channel between in between two circuits in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise

Suppose, you have two parts of a circuit in Qiskit, `qc1` and `qc2` on any number of qubits such that the entire circuit is given by

```
qc = qc1.compose(qc2)
```

For sake of concreteness, here is an example on 2 qubits:

```
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc2 = QuantumCircuit(2)

qc1.h([0,1])
qc2.x(0)
```

I want to apply a single-qubit channel on the first qubit, say a depolarizing one, in between `qc1` and `qc2` and then simulate the whole circuit using qiskit. That is, after `qc1` and before `qc2`. After having looked at the Qiskit Aer `noise` module, my idea would be to introduce a noisy version of an identity gate between the two circuits `qc1` and `qc2`. How to do this?

Comment: Good question!  At least according to the documentation, a noise model applies to an execution and not to a specific piece of a circuit.  https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_noise.html

Comment: Are you open to a classical Monte Carlo like simulation where you execute the circuit again and again? Then you could introduce a u3 gate in between (on a specific qubit) and sample the gate parameters from a distribution of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you describe is precisely the workaround that I am using at the moment. I just find it extremely annoying that I have to manually implement the effect of the noise myself when there is a `noise` module. I am looking for an answer that is native to qiskit.

Comment: You could do something like https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/4_custom_gate_noise.html with a u3 gate.

Comment: @RKRupesh could you come up with some example code?

Comment: Some sample codes are here which might help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/how-to-selectively-apply-noise-in-qiskit-simulations/8571#8571

Comment: Hi @Sam, thanks for the link. I tried the method there. This method works if one wants to apply noise to a custom non-identity gate. However, when I want to use a custom identity gate, it seems that the transpiler always gets rid of the gate before simulating the circuit which results in no noise applied...

Comment: Ah I see. I am guessing you have tried with the optimization_flag set to 0 in the transpile step to prevent transpiler optimization.